# Possible to 'copy and paste' a whole Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a fully-functioning Rails application running on my local machine called 'first-app' in my Rails applications folder 'rails-apps'. I would like to create a second application in rails-apps (called 'second-app') which is identical to first-app, just with a different name.

Can I simply copy-and-paste first-app and rename the folder to 'second-app'? I have found only two files in the whole application which contain the term 'first-app' (application.rb and routes.rb, both in config), so presumably I would have to change their contents as well. If this 'copy-and-paste' approach is viable, are there any other files I would have to alter?

If I have to do the usual > rails new second-app, I must be able to copy and paste a lot of the files and folders from first-app. Which are the ones that I have to manually alter or construct with a rails command?

Comment: Yes, you can duplicate the folder. Just remember to set up a second database for the second app.

Answer (score 3):

yes, it should works! Just replace in the copy-project the old terms('first-app') to 'second-app' and create a new database for the new app.

Comment: You can find all occurences of 'first-app' by command `grep -ri "first-app" .` To list all files containing this phrase, use `grep -irl "first-app" .`

Comment: Does one need to change the secret_token variable?

Comment: Yes. That variable needs to be unique for each app you create.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy and past the first app folder and use the `gem 'rename'` to rename the copied app.
*Follow these instructions:* [How to rename rails 4 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988813/how-to-rename-rails-4-app)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your app to a new folder :

```
$ cp your-old-app your-new-app
```

If you want to create a new database for the new app, in your `config/database.yml` rename the development database.

After that, all you have to do is 
`rake db:create db:migrate`