# How to rename rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

`rails plugin install git://github.com/get/Rename.git` will allow us to rename only rails 3 app

Is there any gem available to rename Rails 4 app.

If not, suggest me the better way to rename.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming Ruby on Rails application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270373/renaming-ruby-on-rails-application)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Since rails **4.1.x**, if you want to rename your application, the only two files you need to modify are `config/application.rb`:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module YourApplicationName # <-- rename it here
   class Application < Rails::Application
     ...
   end
end
```

and `config/initializers/session_store.rb` (optional):

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_application_name_session' # <-- rename the key
```

---

For Rails **4.0.x** you can use the [`rename`](https://github.com/morshedalam/rename) gem and execute the following command:

```
rails g rename:app_to New-Name
```

This will update the necessary files for you:

```
old/ (master)  › rails g rename:app_to new
Search and replace module in to...
    gsub  config.ru
    gsub  Gemfile
    gsub  Gemfile.lock
    gsub  Rakefile
    gsub  README.md
    gsub  config/application.rb
    gsub  config/boot.rb
    gsub  config/environment.rb
    gsub  config/environments/development.rb
    gsub  config/environments/production.rb
    gsub  config/environments/test.rb
    gsub  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
    gsub  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
    gsub  config/initializers/inflections.rb
    gsub  config/initializers/load_class_extensions.rb
    gsub  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
    gsub  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
    gsub  config/initializers/session_store.rb
    gsub  config/initializers/update.rb
    gsub  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
    gsub  config/routes.rb
    gsub  config/initializers/session_store.rb
Renaming references...
Renaming directory...Done!
New application path is '/Users/username/code/new'
```

Comment: The Rails 4.1.x example didn't work for me using Rails 4.1.0. I found that I had to change the name of the module in config/routes.rb as well: `YourApplicationName::Application.routes.draw do`.

Comment: @Adam this is true if you upgrade an existing Rails application to 4.1.x. Running `rake rails:update` changes `YourApplicationName::Application` to `Rails.application`.

Comment: I agree with the 2 files @Daniel mentions for a Rails 4.2.0.beta2 app (`config/application.rb` and `config/initializers/session_store.rb`). You may also find a reference to the app name in the title of `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Comment: You might want to rename the databases in `config/database.yml` too.

Comment: If you follow @yenshirak's advice to rename the database, note that changing the name in `database.yml` only changes the place that it looks for the database, it does not actually rename the database itself. If you change the specified location, you'll also need to rename the database using a tool like `pgadmin` or `psql`. IMO, it's easiest to leave this unchanged.

Comment: I tried to use it with Rails 4.2.0 and the gem also updated the 2 files (session_store.rb and application.rb) :)

Comment: This answer does not change the name on the browser tab.

Comment: Such as view titles and other breadcrumbs of the previous name.

Comment: @jasonleonhard the browser tab title is provided by your layouts `title` tag. Check `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` if you want to change it.

Answer (score 36):

Add

`gem 'rename'` to Gemfile

then

`bundle install`

After that

```
rails g rename:app_to name_of_app
```

And if you are using mongoid then you need to rename the database name in `config/mongoid.yml`

Comment: This currently accepted answer is near identical to the person who posted it first in 2014: @complistic

Comment: While this gem works, it should be used with caution. 
I had an experimental application named admin. When I used rename gem to change its name it also changed all occurences of Admin in comments as well as code to the new name many of which were in fact related to Active Admin. 
It even changes constants of which the project name just happens to be a part of, like : `ActiveAdmin`

Comment: [DEPRECATION] `app_to` is deprecated.  Please use `into` instead.

Answer (score 29):

There are two ways:

**1 . Manually (For Rails 4.1.x)**

You need to manually find the references to the application name. And you need to change them manually. Here is some common places where it is used:

```
config/application.rb
config/environment.rb
config/environments/development.rb
config/environments/production.rb
config/environments/test.rb
config/initializers/secret_token.rb
config/initializers/session_store.rb
config/routes.rb
config.ru
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
Rakefile
```

**2 . Automatic (For Rails 3 and 4.0.X)**

Or you can use the [rename gem](https://github.com/get/rename) and execute the following command:

```
rails g rename:app_to New-Name
```

Comment: Note that the rename gem README says "This plugin will only work for Rails 3 and below."

Comment: I was able to rename my rails application( rails 4.0.4 ) using this gem... Rails 4.1 and later are not supported by this gem.

Answer (score 23):

For **Rails 5**

**Require**

- `config/application.rb` change the module name

**Optional**

- `config/initializers/session_store.rb` (in Rails.application.config.session_store) change the session name
- `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` You can change the `<title>...</title>`, if it is not already done

Comment: Don't forget to change the database names at `config/database.ym` !

Answer (score 16):

I just used this `rename` gem in a basic rails 4 app:

https://github.com/morshedalam/rename

This is quite a bit different to `get`'s version.

---

Easy enough to use:

Add this to Gemfile:

```
gem 'rename'
```

And run:

```
rails g rename:app_to NewName
```

---

Seemed to the trick,
It also updated my rubymine .idea project settings :)

Comment: What is "get's version"?

Comment: The https://github.com/get/rename `plugin` stated in the question and other answer is by the github user `get`, this is completely different to the https://github.com/morshedalam/rename `gem` im talking about, and wanted to make that a bit more obvious. (the later works in Rails 4)

Answer (score 9):

In **Rails 4.2** just change in `application config` file

```
config/application.rb
```

and config/initializers/session_store.rb (optional):

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_application_name_session' # <-- rename the key
```

then restart your server.

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

For rails 5.2

Add `gem 'rename'` to the gemfile

`bundle install`

`rails g rename:into your_new_app_name`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a gem specifically for Rails 4
https://github.com/negativetwelve/rails-rename
(I haven't used it but it seems fine)

The other gems listed here only target Rails 3

Answer (score 0):

**In Rails 5.x, doing it manually**

using ag (https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), there are files that use the default folder name (if generated via rails new .)

three basic files, relative to root of project, need to be updated:

- config/cable.yml > channel_prefix:
- config/environments/production.rb > # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix
- package.json > name

There are sure to be more locations as mentioned previously such as database etc. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**How to Rename a Rails 6.1.3 Application**

the "rename" gem doesn’t appear to be tested against Rails 6 at this time according to their documentation so I opted for the manual route.

- config/database.yml  (rename the 3 databases)
- config/application.rb (rename the module)
- package.json (rename the package name)
- README.md (in case it mentions your old app name)
- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb (rename the title)
- config/cable.yml (name the Channel_prefix database to the new production database)
- Run `npm install` so that the name attribute you previously updated in package.json is registered.
- Run your migrations `rails db:migrate`
- Start your server `rails s`

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 6.1 Here is what I did:
rename module config/application.rb
run `bundle install`
and run `rails db:migrate`.

after that running `rails c` then `Rails.application.class.module_parent.name`