# rails g active_admin:install ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have problem with ActiveAdmin. I've added the gem 'activeadmin' to my Gemfile and ran

```
$ bundle install
```

which worked. But when I try to:

```
$ rails g active_admin:install
```

I get:

```
/home/dominika/active_admin/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>': superclass mismatch for class Application (TypeError)
from /home/dominika/active_admin/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/dominika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
from /home/dominika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
from /home/dominika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
from /home/dominika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /home/dominika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /home/dominika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /home/dominika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/dominika/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/dominika/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Maybe it's really stupid, but I really don't know how to fix it.
Please, help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your application is called `active_admin`. Rename it, and everything will work.

To rename the app view [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988813/how-to-rename-rails-4-app) to get the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Overall it sounds like you are pretty much doing things correctly.

> I've added the gem 'active_admin'

From the documentation it's:

```
# Gemfile

gem 'activeadmin'
```

Does that help?