# Gemfile not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed rails on a Windows 8.1 machine, and tried to get a server up, but when running `rails server` I get the error:

> Gemfile not found

I tried `gem update`, `bundle init`, and so on, but nothing works.

When I run `rails new test_app`, I get the warning

> DL is depreciated, please use Fiddle

My **Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.4)
      actionpack (= 4.2.4)
      actionview (= 4.2.4)
      activejob (= 4.2.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.4)
      actionview (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.4)
      activemodel (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.4)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.3)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (6.0.2)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.3.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.5)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.6.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.8.0)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.4)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.4)
      actionpack (= 4.2.4)
      actionview (= 4.2.4)
      activejob (= 4.2.4)
      activemodel (= 4.2.4)
      activerecord (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.4)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.2.4)
      actionpack (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.4.18)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    sprockets (3.3.4)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.10-x86-mingw32)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2015.6)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    web-console (2.2.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  rails (= 4.2.4)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  sqlite3
  turbolinks
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.6
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: IS there a Gemfile in your app directory?

Comment: Are in inside project directory?

Comment: yes ! a gemfile was generated with 50 lines more or less

Comment: Have you installed the bundler gem?

Comment: just typed in `gem install bundler`, I think I had already done it but just in case... and no success: same error

Comment: If you run `bundle install` from inside the project's folder, what's the result?

Comment: It says I should run `bundle show [gemname]`, if I run an other `rails server`I have the same error

Comment: Could you include the contents of both your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock here please?

Comment: what happens with `bundle exec rails s`? And `ruby -v`?

Comment: `app>bundle exec rails s
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
/app/Gemfile not found

app>ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]`

Comment: in what directory are you working? What is the app directory?

Comment: the app directory is the one created by `rails new app`

Comment: `app` is *not* a good app name. If you haven't done anything yet, [create a new one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-blog-application) with a proper name.

Comment: It gives the same result, I named the first ones `test_server`, I just created a `blog` and it gives the same answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem: 
The user repertory is `Cédric` with and accent on the e as I am french but the special character generated an error in the directory of the Gemfile. 
Changing the directory to `C:\RailsInstaller` for the projects bypasses this bug, it is working now.

Comment: That's epic. Props to you for figuring that out!

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Trying to run `rails server` on a Windows 10 system, results in the error message _"Gemfile not found"_, even though there is indeed a `Gemfile` present within the working directory. This was happening because the working directory path contained a `Ø` (Norwegian character). Perhaps this is a bug that should be reported to the Rails team?

Comment: I am still getting this bug almost 6 years since you've had it, thank you for this. My path is in Japanese and it breaks a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are in the wrong directory.

You seem to be in `some_project/app/`, you need to call

```
cd ..
```

to get to the *project* directory. Then you should easily be able to start your server.

```
rails s
```

---

My second guess is that the error is caused due to your app name `app`. I would create a new one or [change it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988813/how-to-rename-rails-4-app).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Windows 10, but none of the answers above worked. I wound up moving my application to different directory levels and found that once I moved the application directory out of the OneDrive directory (or any subdirectory), it worked fine. So I suspect it could be some sort of OneDrive syncing mechanism that prevents the Gemfile file from being seen by bundle.

In fact, after getting `bundle install` to work from c:\Users[my user directory][my app directory], I tried moving my application back to c:\Users[my user directory]\OneDrive[my app directory] just to see what would happen. `bundle install` worked for a little bit and actually failed mid execution like so:

```
...
Using uglifier 4.1.9
Using wdm 0.1.1
Using web-console 3.6.0
Could not locate Gemfile
```

So, probably some sort of OneDrive syncing that caught up to and "hid" the Gemfile.

I'd be curious to hear from Cedric and Leif if that might have been their actual problem too.

Comment: Nope, I was not using any form of Cloud at the time, as I said fixing the accent worked